# Substitution of adverb by another "equivalent" word?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

In the sentence: *Her voice sounds beautiful. She sang the song exactly as it was written. We heard it perfectly.* Isn't it feasible to substitute the last word by "perfect"? In Spanish both ways are valid but sounds better the second option. Even more, I feel that the second/third sentence can be deleted without grammatical ambiguity. Bye.

Comment: I think a native speaker would be more likely to say *It sounded perfect*; to *hear perfectly* describes your hearing, not the singer or the song.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically *perfect* may replace *beautiful*, but it does not necessarily have the same meaning (which is what I think you are asking). Her singing voice may be *beautiful* to the ear, but still have faults, especially if it is a singing teacher who says this!

If you mean *perfect* to replace *perfectly*, the answer is no. *Sound* is one of those verbs like *seem*, *appear*, *look* which may take an adjectival complement, but most verbs cannot; in particular **hear it perfect* is not grammatical.

As for deleting the second and third sentences: there is no grammatical ambiguity in doing so, but it removes a corresponding part of the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the last word of the first sentence? If so, yes. 'Her voice sounds perfect' is good grammar. In this instance 'perfect' is an adjective describing 'her voice'. see choster's comment above.